# Is there any reasons not to make friends?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

When a Yo-Kai likes me enough after a battle, they might ask to be my friend. Is there any reason to say no to this? Saying yes means I can add them to my party, but I don't want to risk anything by saying no before I know what happens.

Comment: I am on the other side of this question. I have not taken on any duplicates. While I feel a twinge of guilt when they walk sadly away, I am wondering what benefit I might be missing out on by rejecting them.